# Replace string action for SPD 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-variable, email-templates

I'm working on an approval workflow and I need to send email during the approval/reject process.

I have an email template list through which I fetch the body for the email.
The body for one of the status looks like below:

> Your timesheet for #month# has been rejected.
>
> Kindly refer below comments of #approver# :

I want to replace the #month# and #approver# dynamically with a Workflow: Variable.

However, I'm able to do so with SPD 2013 workflow using "Replace string" action. But I want to do the same with SPD 2010 workflow.

Can anyone help me in achieving this using SPD 2010 workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "month" is a SharePoint column, click the Add or Change Lookup button to add your values from the list's columns.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Sir
But as I said in my question, the body of the email should be get from the EmailTemplate list because it may change in future.
All I have to do is change the month and approver dynamically.

Comment: Is the "EmailTemplate" just a Single Line of Text string?

Comment: No. 
The body column inside the EmailTemplate list is a multi lines of text field.